# How to position my slideshow next to paragraph

Tags: css, position

On my [homesite](https://akela.mendelu.cz/~xloksik/lubo2/) I have slideshow with cars. My problem is, that slideshow is on the next line (or block I should say) under paragraph "Vitajte!". I want that slideshow next to paragraph "Vitajte!" on the right side. Here is [link on my CSS](https://akela.mendelu.cz/~xloksik/lubo2/styles.css). Thx for help :)

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/ to share your css and html codes

Comment: `div#welcome { float:left; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
float:left;
```

to div#welcome;

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make the below changes to your CSS and get the paragraph to align right.

**The CSS:**

```
div#welcome {
    display: inline;
    height: 148px;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: right;
    width: 290px;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to keep the paragraph to the same place and move the slideshow inline with the paragraph, you need to add a `float:left` to the `div#welcome`

**For Instance,**

```
div#welcome {
             float:left;
            }
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thx, but I want only move slideshow on the right side next to paragraph "vitajte!". Paragraph "vitajte!" should stay as it is.

Comment: Then you need to add a `float:left` to the `div#welcome` - @kocourPB

Answer (score 0):

```
div#welcome
{
float: left;
}
```

Add the above css to the div, which will bring your slider to right side. If you want to move the slider little down and move left add

```
.ppy-placeholder
{
margin-top: 55px !important;
width: 450px !important;
}
```